# Xpath where parent and child both have attribute - htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have something like this,

```
<div class="rightpanel">
.
.
<ul..>...</ul>
<ul class="side-panel categories"></ul>
.
</div>
```

I am trying to select the ul having class side-panel categories with the htmlagilitypack.

I have tried,

```
HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='right-panel']/ul[@class='side-panel categories']")
```

but it's giving me a nullreference exception ...
please help.

Answer (score 2):

In the HTML, the div has the class `rightpanel`, but in your XPath it's `right-panel`. Please try this:

```
HtmlDocument.DocumentNode
      .SelectNodes("//div[@class='rightpanel']/ul[@class='side-panel categories']")
```

And if the `<ul>` is not a direct child of the `<div>` (i.e. if it had a parent that was not the `<div>` itself, you would need this:

```
HtmlDocument.DocumentNode
      .SelectNodes("//div[@class='rightpanel']//ul[@class='side-panel categories']")
```

with a double-slash before the `ul`.